# MySQL Data not showing

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, database-connection

I've connected to my database in laravel - which was previously working on a mac - and everything works fine after I migrate. However, none of the data in the database seems to be showing.

Here's the migration file:

```php
 <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePagesTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->index();
            $table->string('uri')->index();

            $table->integer('parent_id')->default(0)->index();
            $table->string('template')->default('default');

            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('pages');
    }
}
```

and the database.php file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => array(
            'read' => array(
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            ),
            'write' => array(
                'host' => '127.0.0.1'
            ),

            'driver'      => 'mysql',
            'host'        => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE', '5thwall'),
            'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'port'        => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'charset'     => 'utf8',
            'collation'   => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', null),
            'prefix'      => '',
            'strict'      => false,
        ),

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 3306,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

My .env file is fine, presumably, because it's connecting to the database but not loading any content. If there's anything else I can provide, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `not loading`?. I mean, do you have any datas in the database table and they are not loading or the `table` is not being created after migration?

Comment: the table created after migration. it was a stupid error on my behalf - the website wasn't built by myself, i took it over as a new developer and they didn't leave me with the database. once imported all is fine.